# linear-gradient animation not working on ios safari

Tags: ios, css, safari, css-animations

I cannot figure out why this linear-gradient animation will not work on Ios safari, neither on desktop safari. Works like a charm on Chrome though.

```
.shining {
  -webkit-animation-name: shining;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.12,.89,.98,.47);
}

@-webkit-keyframes shining {
  0% {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
                    top left,
                    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 0,
                    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 45%,
                    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 48%,
                    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 50%,
                    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 52%,
                    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 57%,
                    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
    );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -250px -250px;
    background-size: 600px 600px;
  }
  100% {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:250px 250px;
  }
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you explain what is not working, what do you see, perhaps add a picture.

Comment: I create this fiddle, but seems it works only with chrome.
https://jsfiddle.net/spc4hpq7/1/

Comment: Nothing happens, the shining effect does not appear at all

Comment: Have you tried using non-prefixed declarations for 'animation' and 'keyframes' or have you been using only the -webkit- ones ?